# ¿Crear archivo con fecha y hora del sistema?

Tags: java

bueno verán trato de crear un archivo donde se va a escribir los datos de un cliente y la mascota  pero eso ya lo hago en un metodo y funciona el problema es que todo lo guardaba en un mismo .txt y al ingresar varios clientes y mascotas se llega a confundir por bastante informacion, asi que lo que quiero hacer es guardar un cliente y mascota en distintos .txt los cuales tendran de titulo la fecha y hora del sistema asi al ingresar el cliente y mascota varias veces se crearan varios .txt ya que cada uno tendra un nombre distinto, el problema es que me da un error al crear el archivo

```
public class pruebahora {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Date date = new Date();
    DateFormat hourdateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss dd/MM/yyyy");
    String historial = hourdateFormat.format(date);
    FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream(historial+".txt");
}
}
```

en ese metodo se supone de crear el archivo .txt que tendra la hora y fecha mas la extension .txt pero me marca este error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: 19:32:31 20\05\2018.txt (El nombre de archivo, el nombre de directorio o la sintaxis de la etiqueta del volumen no son correctos)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at pruebahora.main(pruebahora.java:14)
```

entonces me gustaría que me ayudaran a ver por que no puedo crear el archivo con la fecha y hora del sistema

Comment: Ese formato de nombre de directorio es proclive a muchos líos en Java. Tienes que escapar los espacios y los backslashes `\\` en el nombre para que sea válido.

Comment: El problema es que el nombre del archivo que estás creando tiene caracteres ilegales en Windows como los dos puntos (:) y los backslash (\).

Comment: Gracias ya cambie formato y funciona

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Construyes mal el nombre del fichero, no se pueden poner `/` ni `:` en los nombres de archivos.
Tu código debería quedar así:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Date date = new Date();
        DateFormat hourdateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH.mm.ss dd-MM-yyyy");
        String historial = hourdateFormat.format(date);
        try {
            FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream(historial+".txt");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Resultado en la carpeta del WORKSPACE :

[image: fichero_correcto]